# Open additional data on receiving push notification

Tags: android, json

I created a sample app and using Pushwoosh I am able to receive the notification, and on click, it opens app, however when I want to send additional data then it does not display that.

1. I have added the code below.
2. I have searched for relevant questions but nothing elates. This is the data i'm trying to pass to app.

```js
{"employees":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]}
```

Here is the MainActivity

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String bTAG = "example";

    boolean broadcastPush = true;

    JSONAdapter jsonAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();

        String userNameText = "";


        JSONObject json = null;
        try
        {
            json = new JSONObject(userNameText);
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONArray array = null;
        try
        {
            JSONObject userdataObject = json.getJSONObject("userdata");

            array = userdataObject.getJSONArray("employees");
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        //Set the adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
        jsonAdapter = new JSONAdapter(this, array);

        //here we register receivers for push notifications
        registerReceivers();

        final PushManager pushManager = PushManager.getInstance(this);

        //Now we start the push manager, this will count app open for Pushwoosh stats as well
        try
        {
            pushManager.onStartup(this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //now we register for push notification
        pushManager.registerForPushNotifications();

        //then check launch notification
        String launchNotification = pushManager.getLaunchNotification();
        if(launchNotification != null)
        {
            Log.d(bTAG, "Launch notification received" + launchNotification);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(bTAG, "No notification received");
        }

        //Clear application icon badge number
        pushManager.setBadgeNumber(0);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity receives a new intent.
     */
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        //have to check if we've got new intent as a part of push notification
        try {
            checkMessage(intent);
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Registration receiver
    BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BaseRegistrationReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRegisterActionReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            try {
                checkMessage(intent);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    //Push message receiver
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BasePushMessageReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        protected void onMessageReceive(Intent intent)
        {
            //JSON_DATA_KEY contains JSON payload of push notification.
            try
            {
                doOnMessageReceive(intent.getExtras().getString(JSON_DATA_KEY));
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    //Registration of the receivers
    public void registerReceivers()
    {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(getPackageName() + ".action.PUSH_MESSAGE_RECEIVE");

        if (broadcastPush)
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter, getPackageName() +".permission.C2D_MESSAGE", null);

        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(getPackageName() + "." + PushManager.REGISTER_BROAD_CAST_ACTION));

    }

    public void unregisterReceivers()
    {
        //Unregister receivers on pause
        try
        {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // pass.
        }

        try
        {
            unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //pass through
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        //Re-register receivers on resume
        registerReceivers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        //Unregister receivers on pause
        unregisterReceivers();
    }

    /**
     * Will check PushWoosh extras in this intent, and fire actual method
     *
     * @param intent activity intent
     */
    private void checkMessage(Intent intent) throws JSONException {
        if (null != intent)
        {
            if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT))
            {
                doOnMessageReceive(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT));
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT))
            {
                doOnRegistered(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT));
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT))
            {
                doOnUnregistered(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT));
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT))
            {
                doOnRegisteredError(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT));
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT))
            {
                doOnUnregisteredError(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT));
            }

            resetIntentValues();
        }
    }

    public void doOnRegistered(String registrationId)
    {
        Log.d(bTAG, "registered: " + registrationId);
    }

    public void doOnRegisteredError(String errorId)
    {
        Log.d(bTAG, "registration error: " + errorId);
    }

    public void doOnUnregistered(String registrationId)
    {
        Log.d(bTAG, "unregistered: " + registrationId);
    }

    public void doOnUnregisteredError(String errorId)
    {
        Log.d(bTAG, "deregistration error: " + errorId);
    }

    public void doOnMessageReceive(String message) throws JSONException
    {
        Log.d(bTAG, "received push: " + message);

        JSONObject json  = new JSONObject(message);
        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("employees");

        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will check main Activity intent and if it contains any PushWoosh data, will clear it
     */
    private void resetIntentValues()
    {
        Intent mainAppIntent = getIntent();

        if (mainAppIntent.hasExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT))
        {
            mainAppIntent.removeExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT);
        }
        else if (mainAppIntent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT))
        {
            mainAppIntent.removeExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT);
        }
        else if (mainAppIntent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT))
        {
            mainAppIntent.removeExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT);
        }
        else if (mainAppIntent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT))
        {
            mainAppIntent.removeExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT);
        }
        else if (mainAppIntent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT))
        {
            mainAppIntent.removeExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT);
        }

        setIntent(mainAppIntent);
    }

}
```

And here is the Adapter

```js
class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private final Activity activity;
    private final JSONArray jsonArray;
    public JSONAdapter (Activity activity, JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        assert activity != null;
        assert jsonArray != null;

        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    @Override public int getCount() {
        if(null==jsonArray)
            return 0;
        else
            return jsonArray.length();
    }

    @Override public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
        if(null==jsonArray) return null;
        else
            return jsonArray.optJSONObject(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = getItem(position);

        return jsonObject.optLong("id");
    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_name_list, null);

        TextView text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        JSONObject json_data = getItem(position);

        if(null!=json_data )
        {
            try {
                text.setText(json_data.getString("firstName"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Please assist as I'm not too sure how to get the additional data I added on Pushwoosh to display in the app without hard coding it.